# docker --net vs --network

Tags: docker, docker-network

i can't seem to find a good explanation for the reason behind using `--net` vs `--network` with docker. 
`--help` doesn't show `--net` but only shows `--network`, can somebody please explain the difference ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`--network` and `--net` options in the Docker are the same and work similarly. But `--net` is shorter in use.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options

For more information:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24145
and 
https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/23324